# Is there a way to capture bugs that pop up in excel rather that looking through the event viewer etc

Tags: excel, debugging

I am working on a spreadsheet with heavy macros and see that it sometimes crashes. Really appreciate any tips

Comment: Try to close any background tasks running on your computer. If a program crashes from heavy load it's because you computer can't take it any more.

Comment: Crashes fully, or merely becomes unresponsive? Unresponsive *usually* resolves itself after some time has elapsed -- problem is that we are usually not patient enough and then we start doing things like ctrl+alt+del...  In the case of "unresponsiveness", the macros may just be "busy" executing code, and in that case the problem is probably one of optimizing your code for efficiency.

Comment: I have added a batch file that kills Excel "taskkill /F /IM EXCEL.EXE" but the problem I am having is that the macros are running at as the spread sheet opens... as soon as you press a drop down button it crashes. However if you lick elsewhere before you click that dropdown it will not crash. Weird.. I am looking for a way to debug the startup macros to find out what the problem might be.